# How hard is it to waste large amounts of electricity?

Tags: electricity

It sometimes happens that utilities have so much energy they have to *pay* other utilities to take it. From https://www.latimes.com/projects/la-fi-electricity-solar/:

> On 14 days during March, Arizona utilities got a gift from California:
> free solar power.
>
> Well, actually better than free. California produced so much solar
> power on those days that it paid Arizona to take excess electricity
> its residents weren’t using to avoid overloading its own power lines.

Why can't these utilities just throw it away? Aren't there cheap and easy ways to *waste* electricity? Boil some water, lift a heavy rock and then drop it, stir some molasses, ...?

Comment: Cheap and easy ways to waste electricity at the scale of a utility requires careful engineering and capital investment, making it neither cheap nor easy...

Comment: very difficult because electric energy is very concentrated and when it is dumped in a resistor it immediately and completely generates an equal amount of heat that can quickly turn into ashes everything around it. It is also difficult to handle large voltages and large currents, fluctuations, even if their product, that is energy rate= power, is not too high otherwise. All circuit components are limited in the maximum they can handle of the parameters power, voltage, current, and let's not forget, in their time rates of increase.

Comment: Google "pumped storage hydroelectricity"...but once you run out of water pumps to run, it might be cheaper to pay another region to take your excess power than to build more reservoirs and pumps.